# Report Viewer Schema 2016

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Ao adicionar um parâmetro em um relatório do `ReportViewer` está acontecendo de a versão do `schema` mudar para a 2016, o que me acarreta no seguinte erro ao tentar renderizar o relatório

> Message: Test method
>   Syns.Web.Teste.Relatorios.DemonstrativoReportTest.MyTestMethodAsync
>   threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: An error
>   occurred during local report processing. --->
>   Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the
>   report
>   'D:\Projetos\Syns\Syns\Syns.Web\Relatorios\DemonstrativoReport.rdlc'
>   is invalid. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
>   The report definition is not valid or supported by this version of
>   Reporting Services. This could be the result of publishing a report
>   definition of a later version of Reporting Services, or that the
>   report definition contains XML that is not well-formed or the XML is
>   not valid based on the Report Definition schema. Details: The report
>   definition has an invalid target namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition'
>   which cannot be upgraded.

O código que uso para renderizar o relatório é basicamente o seguinte

```
public async Task<ReportModel> Report(int demonstrativoId, string path)
{
    var demonstrativo = await Demonstrativo(demonstrativoId);
    var demonstrativos = new List<Demonstrativo>()
    {
        demonstrativo
    };

    var procedimentos = await DemonstrativoProcedimento(demonstrativoId);

    LocalReport relat = new LocalReport
    {
        //caminho do arquivo rdlc
        ReportPath = Path.Combine(path, "DemonstrativoReport.rdlc"),
        EnableExternalImages = true,
    };

    //vinculando dataset ao objeto relat            
    relat.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource
    {
        Name = "DemonstrativoDataSet",
        Value = demonstrativos
    });
    relat.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource()
    {
        Name = "DemonstrativoProcedimentoDataSet",
        Value = procedimentos,
    });
    relat.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("NumeroDemonstrativoParam", demonstrativo.Numero.ToString()));

    //definindo tipo que o relatório será renderizado
    string reportType = "PDF";

    //configurações da página ex: margin, top, left ...
    string deviceInfo =
    "<DeviceInfo>" +
    "<OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
    "<PageWidth>8.27in</PageWidth>" +
    "<PageHeight>11.69in</PageHeight>" +
    "<MarginTop>0.19685in</MarginTop>" +
    "<MarginLeft>0.19685in</MarginLeft>" +
    "<MarginRight>0.19685in</MarginRight>" +
    "<MarginBottom>0.19685in</MarginBottom>" +
    "</DeviceInfo>";

    byte[] bytes;
    //Renderizando o relatório o bytes
    bytes = relat.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out string mimeType, out string encoding, out string fileNameExtension, out string[] streams, out Warning[] warnings);

    return new ReportModel(bytes, mimeType);
}
```

Se eu alterar o schema do ReportViewer para o 2008, remover algumas tags da versão 2016, o meu código funciona, porém sempre que eu volta a editar o relatório, a versão volta para a 2016.

Fiz um exemplo e subi para o github, a diferença do arquivo do ReportViewer pode ser visto no commit https://github.com/pablotdv/WebApplication3/commit/ee48445507051a78afe59e18384c110ea3b230c7

Answer (score 2):

Uma possível solução é baixar uma extensão que que faz essa troca de referencias automaticamente. Essa extensão é a ChangeReportDefinition, depois de alterar todo o documento .rdlc aperte com botão direito nele e clica na opção Change Report Definition.